# De Moivre's paradox

Tags: probability, paradoxes

According to Bernoulli's law of large numbers, in the coin tossing game  the probability that the number of heads equal to the number of tails tends to $1$ as number of tosses increases.

In other words  :

$\frac{H(n)}{T(n)}$ tends to $1$ as $n$ $\to$ $\infty$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P \bigg( \frac{H(n)}{T(n)}=1 \bigg)=1$$
where $H(n)$ and $T(n)$ denote the number of heads and tails, in $n$ tosses of coin.

On the other hand, the probability that the number of heads is 
exactly equal to the number of tails tends to zero.

when tossing $2n$ times, the 
the probability that it falls heads exactly $n$ times is  $p(n)=2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}p(n)=0$$

The probability that the number of heads 
approximately equals the number of tails tends to one, whereas the probability that the number of heads is exactly equal to the number of tails 
tends to zero.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P \bigg( H(n)=T(n) \bigg)=0$$

Can anyone explain this  contradiction?

Comment: The probability that $\frac{H(n)}{T(n)}$ approaches 1 is not the same as the probability that $\frac{H(n)}{T(n)}$ is equal to 1.

Comment: This can't be formulated correctly, because the two events you have written are the same. I think you mean something very different, namely $P \left (\frac{H(n)}{T(n)} \to 1 \right ) = 1$. In this formulation there is no contradiction because $\frac{H(n)}{T(n)}$ can tend to $1$ provided $H(n)$ is merely not too far away from $T(n)$, since they both diverge with probability 1.

Comment: The explanation for the contradiction is simple: The law of large numbers simply does not say what you say it does.

Answer (score 4):

The strong law of large numbers says
$$
\Pr\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{H(n)}{T(n)} = 1 \right) = 1.
$$
The law **does not say**:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr \left( \frac{H(n)}{T(n)}=1 \right)=1,
$$
which is different and in fact false.

(The **weak** law of large numbers says $\displaystyle\forall\varepsilon>0\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr\left( 1-\varepsilon<\frac{H(n)}{T(n)}<1+\varepsilon \right)=1$.)

Comment: A minor point: the law also tells us that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H(n)}{T(n)}$ *exists* with probability 1, in addition to what it actually is. Note that the issue of existence is not trivial, since I think this limit does *not* exist on the entire sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: @Ian : I take the assertion of existence of the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ to be included in the statement $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n)=A$. $\qquad$

Comment: Indeed this is a common convention and it is perfectly fine as long as it is understood.